# Mixing $SU(N)$ and $U(1)$ generators to form an unbroken $U(1)’$

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, group-theory, fermions, symmetry-breaking

I’m trying to understand some symmetry breaking patterns and have been reading David Tong’s [Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) notes for an overview. I’m getting very confused about how one can mix $SU(N)$ and $U(1)$ generators as he does on page 295. He considers the famous GUT theory
$$
    G=SU(5) \text{ with two left handed Weyl spinors} \\
    \chi_{ij} \text{ in } \mathbf{10} \text{ and } \psi^i \text{ in } \mathbf{\bar{5}},
$$

where $i,j=1,...,5$ are the (anti)fundamental $SU(5)$ gauge group indices. This theory has a single non-anomolous global $U(1)$ symmetry with charges $Q(\psi)=3$ and  $Q(\chi)=-1$. Then we assume the following condensates form

\begin{equation}
\langle \psi^i \chi_{ij} \rangle = \sigma \delta_{j,1}, \:\:\:\:\:\: \langle \chi_{ij} \chi_{kl} \rangle=\epsilon_{ijklm}\Delta \delta^{m,1}
\end{equation}

These seem to break the global $U(1)$ but he says: ”We can define a new unbroken global symmetry ($U(1)’$) by mixing the $U(1)$ with a suitable generator of the $SU(5)$ gauge symmetry”

\begin{equation}
Q’:=Q-\dfrac{1}{2}\text{diag}(4,-1,-1,-1,-1)
\end{equation}

How does this act on the charged fermions and in particular how are the condensates above not charged under this new $U(1)’$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do the exact same thing in the standard model when we break the electroweak symmetry. There are 3 broken generators $\delta_-/2, \sigma_1/2, \sigma_2/2$, and a leftover preserved $U(1)_{EM}$ generator, $\delta_+/2$, where

$$
\delta_\pm = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{1}\pm \sigma_3)
$$

are **linear combinations** of the EW gauge group generators. You can verify that these generators span the same space as the original $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$ generators.

You can simply just think of this as a choice of basis for the Lie Algebra that makes the leftover $U(1)$ symmetry manifest.